# What is the tablet/application being used in this 737?

Tags: commercial-aviation, avionics

[In this video (marker 2:32)](https://youtu.be/H6UHAl1Ysyg?t=2m32s), you can see that the captain has a tablet mounted to his left with some sort of application open in it. It looks like an iPad (though I could be wrong), but what I'm mostly wondering is what that application is he has open, and what it's being used for?

---

Just to make peoples lives as bit easier, here's a screen cap from 2:32:

[image]

Comment: I don't know enough to answer, but it's probably a company-specific "electronic flight bag" application, allowing him to access his pilot's log, the aircraft's maintenance log, loading/balance calculations for the flight, airport arrival/departure schedule, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The screens on both electronic flight bags show airspeeds, which would indicate performance data. Specifically, the first officer has a speed card up.

I can't say for certain, but I think the pilot is using the iPad version of the [Boeing Onboard Performance Tool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/boeing-onboard-performance/id584211407?mt=8). This application is used for weight and balance and performance calculations (which is especially appropriate, since they're flying a Boeing aircraft).

Comment: Definitely the Boeing Onboard Performance Tool. Here you can find an [official Boeing impression](http://boeing.mediaroom.com/2012-09-06-Boeing-Onboard-Performance-Solution-for-iPad-to-be-Launched-by-Qantas#assets_117) of the screen which shows the letters `ATM` in the background. These are visible in the youtube video as well.

Comment: If you could include @DeltaLima's link in your answer as well, I think we can call this one complete :D.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [BBC News report](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-32513066), American Airlines uses an app called "FliteDeck" on a tablet computer, to avoid pilots having to carry multiple kilograms of documents with them. It says AA saves over a million dollars a year in fuel bills from not carrying all that paper around.  The app contains charts and things like that.

Other airlines use similar systems so that's probably what we're seeing in Air Vanuatu cockpit in the video.